# TouchesMoved stops firing for no reason

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I added a custom gesture recognizer to a ViewController's view. Once a touch starts, the custom class reports the touch.force in NSLog every time the touchesMoved function fires off.

If you start touching and the move your finger even just a few millimeters, then the touchesMoved events will fire off continually until you lift up your finger and the touchesEnded event fires.

However if you start touching and DON'T move your finger at all, then the touchesMoved events will only fire off a few times, maybe 10-20 times, and then they just stop. After that, the touchesCancelled function does not get called and neither does touchesEnded.

Why is this happening? I want it to keep firing touchesMoved forever until the finger is lifted up.

I saw this other similar question here: [iOS app stops responding to touch events until I move my finger on/off screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476887/ios-app-stops-responding-to-touch-events-until-i-move-my-finger-on-off-screen)

But there is no answer to that one either.

Comment: You expect to receive touchesMoved events even when the touch doesn't move?